# Registering components globally in Vuejs in subfolders

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I have followed the documentation on the Vuejs website to learn how to register vue components globally.

I have defined that the relative path of the components folder is `./global` and set to look in subfolder to `true` (default false). However, it still doesn't look into subfolders.

I have also console.logged the components keys to see if any vue components are included, but it only returned the components in the global (root) folder.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import upperFirst from 'lodash/upperFirst'
import camelCase from 'lodash/camelCase'

const requireComponent = require.context(
  // The relative path of the components folder
  './global',
  // Whether or not to look in subfolders
  true,
  // The regular expression used to match base component filenames
  /[A-Z]\w+\.(vue|js)$/
)

console.log(requireComponent.keys())

requireComponent.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  // Get component config
  const componentConfig = requireComponent(fileName)

  // Get PascalCase name of component
  const componentName = upperFirst(
    camelCase(
      // Strip the leading `./` and extension from the filename
      fileName.replace(/^\.\/(.*)\.\w+$/, '$1')
    )
  )

  // Register component globally
  Vue.component(
    componentName,
    // Look for the component options on `.default`, which will
    // exist if the component was exported with `export default`,
    // otherwise fall back to module's root.
    componentConfig.default || componentConfig
  )
})
```

Comment: Are the component files in the subdirectories named correctly? They should start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what I ended up writing to achieve this same outcome:

```
const requireComponent = require.context(
  // The relative path of the components folder
  './global',
  // Whether or not to look in subfolders
  true,
  // The regular expression used to match base component filenames
  /[A-Z]\w+\.(vue|js)$/
)

requireComponent.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  // Get component config
  const componentConfig = requireComponent(fileName)
  // Get PascalCase name of component
  const componentName = Vue._.upperFirst(
    Vue._.camelCase(
      fileName
        .split('/')
        .pop()
        .replace(/\.\w+$/, '')
    )
  )

  // Register component globally
  Vue.component(
    componentName,
    // Look for the component options on `.default`, which will
    // exist if the component was exported with `export default`,
    // otherwise fall back to module's root.
    componentConfig.default || componentConfig
  )
})
```

Make sure all of you files in global are capitalized and have a .vue or .js extention.

Also with the path you provided make sure that main.js (or whatever your bootstrap file is called) lives one directory up from globals. Example:

/src
  main.js
  /global

This will make the a file such as ProgressBar.vue globally available in all of your components as ProgressBar

```
<ProgressBar></ProgressBar>
```

Comment: Thanks! How come the one provided in the documentation doesn't work? It should work by default when I change the "look in the subfolder" variable to true, no?

Comment: I'm also confused as to why the provided docs didn't work. This seems like it should be built into the subfolder traversal logic...

Comment: I will submit a commit to the VueJS docs repo for consideration.

Answer (score 0):

@Anson C

```js
const requireComponent = require.context(
  // The relative path of the components folder
  './global',
  // Whether or not to look in subfolders
  true,
  // The regular expression used to match base component filenames
  /[A-Z]\w+\.(vue|js)$/
)
```

This code is exactly working as meant to be. Means it will return you back all files in subfolders as expected (like for `./Base/BaseInput.vue` will return `BaseInput`). But to import those files, You have to add the corresponding path as well.

```js
// Get PascalCase name of component
  const componentName = upperFirst(
    camelCase(
      // Strip the leading `./` and extension from the filename
      fileName.replace(/^\.\/(.*)\.\w+$/, '$1')
    )
  )
```

This will only import `./BaseInput` which is not accurate path it shall be `./Base/BaseInput`.

There for:

```js
// Get PascalCase name of component
  const componentName = Vue._.upperFirst(
    Vue._.camelCase(
      fileName
        .split('/')
        .pop()
        .replace(/\.\w+$/, '')
    )
  )
```

This code returns perfect path to the file and folder.