# Is there a way to import globally list of components from specific folder?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli-3

Instead of:

```
import comp1 from './widgets/comp1.vue';
import comp2 from './widgets/comp2.vue';
import comp3 from './widgets/comp3.vue';
...


    export default{
        components: {
            comp1,
            comp2,
            comp3, 
             ...

        },
```

If I don't wanna do `Vue.use` on eace component globally, how can I insert the full widgets folder for all the components inside of it to be register. Any idea?

Comment: did you try this answer here ?? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53678945